# Excel VBA - Copy rows from top to bottom if value is not 0,00

Tags: vba, excel, range

I'm trying to create this Excel macro which basically copies the entire columns from A to F into a separate spreadsheet. But only if the value in Dx is not 0,00. For example, the value in C18 might be 11 etc, but the value in D18 might be 0,00. If that's the case, do not copy that row. Can this be accomplished in an easy matter?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: No, because I have no idea where to even start! I'm pretty used to Word vba, but Excel vba is somehow of a different world. I haven't learned how to target cells, columns and rows yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. You will need to change out the Workbook and Worksheet names in the code:

```
Sub CopyTest()

Dim fromWB As Workbook
Dim toWB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Set fromWB = Application.Workbooks("WBName.xls")
Set toWB = Application.Workbooks("OtherWBName.xls")

For i = 1 To fromWB.Worksheets("WSName").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If fromWB.Worksheets("WSName").Cells(i, 4) <> "0,00" Then
        fromWB.Worksheets("WSName").Rows(i).Copy
        toWB.Worksheets("OtherWSName").Cells(i, 1).Paste
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a start! :) However, it's all happening in the same workbook, it's just separate sheets. Also, it's not specifically column 4 that might be 0. All of the cells MIGHT be 0. Basically, all I want is to copy all specified columns and each row in those that are NOT 0 or 0,00. I'll try some things out myself, but please, if you have any ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best off by turning your range into a table and using an [AutoFilter](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html).  You can then [copy](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter03.html#Copy) the filtered rows to another sheet.

Another option would be to copy everything into an array, and then copy the desired rows into another array, writing it out in the end.  I think this might be less efficient.

Comment: Mmm, but I need to trigger this to happen automatically. I want it to happen on the Document_Open trigger. So I think it needs to be a macro.

Comment: @Kenny A table can be formed using a macro

Comment: @Kenny Samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637097(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: @Kenny At the top of this [page](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp) there is a better example of the table creation itself, the MSDN didn't go into it as well as I thought it would, sorry about that one.

Comment: Are there any real advantages of using tables? It's basically the sort functions that are neat? I'm gonna look a bit into it. So I can for example create a table of the entire columns I'm after. And then use sorting to sort out the rows in that column that contains "0" or "0,00" ?

Comment: @Kenny The filtering is nice, because you don't have to destroy your dataset to get to the information (you can ask it to display rows that contain 0,00, and the others disappear, but can be brought back with the change of filter).  Excel's sorting capabilities are already fairly powerful, but this adds to it, IMO.  I was reading that these things were referred to as "Excel Lists" in Office 2003, so you may need to hunt that menu option down to get these capabilities.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried to use a simple formula instead. =IF(Sheet1!A2<>0;Sheet1!A2;"") Wouldn't this basically do the same job?

Comment: @Kenny I thought you wanted the whole row, though?

Comment: Well yeah that would be the best. But it is possible to just expand the formula if needed. That would be a manual job though. And less manual jobs are the best in my oppinion. The case would be how much time it would take to create the macro versus using a formula.